# Hot Meta Questions not updating title

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, caching, community-bulletin

I clicked on the Hot Meta Post just now, entitled "Double Review Bar bug". However, upon clicking it, I saw a Meta question with a different title, which I found to be the title of the original question. 
[image]

Answer (score 5):

The "Hot Meta Posts" section is cached. Neither title nor score changes will automatically update that section. However, the next time that post hits the "Hot Meta Posts" section, if it does, it will have its latest version of the title and its most recent score.

Comment: The cache resets every hour, if I remember correctly.